# I want to make a function more reusable by using a variable name store inside of a function parameter. How would I do that?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function more reusable by being able to give variable name to it and modify the value of that variable within the function from that variable.

Kind of like this:

```
var number1;
function one(){
  number1 = 10;
  two(number1);
}
function two(varname){
  varname = varname * 10;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You should instead make the function return the result, and assign the variable the result of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send the variable through as a string, you can reference it using `this`

```js
var number1;
function one(){
  number1 = 10;
  two("number1");
}
function two(varname){
  this[varname] = this[varname] * 10;
}

one()
console.log(number1)
```

Comment: Doesn't this rely on the fact that `var` declares global variables that are stored on `globalThis`

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to arrays?